# Is it possible to put a function somewhere other than the functions.php file?

Tags: functions

Is it possible to put a function somewhere other than the functions.php file? I.e directly into a template?

I have the following that needs to be called before some code and to make sure this happens I want to place it above everything else in the template:

```
function set_region_cookie()
{
    if(isset($_POST['region']))
    {
        // Set Cookie
        setcookie('region', $_POST['region'], time()+1209600);
        // Reload the current page so that the cookie is sent with the request
        header('Region: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'set_region_cookie');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using init "add_action", then it is best not to use it in a template - since "add_action" is used by Wordpress core's "do_action" - which comes before the templates.

If you want this function to take higher priority, place it in functions.php but use the 'priority' variable of "add_action":

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority );
```

The default priority is 10. [See more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Alternatively, if this is relevant only for a specific template, then I don't think you need add_action at all - or even a function for that matter.

Simply place the inner code of your function BEFORE get_header() in your template:

```
if(isset($_POST['region']))
{
    // Set Cookie
    setcookie('region', $_POST['region'], time()+1209600);
    // Reload the current page so that the cookie is sent with the request
    header('Region: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can put function in anywhere in template. But, that function used for that template only.

Comment: That doesn't work for functions that are hooked to a hook that did run previously. Hooking into `init` for a function placed inside a template is _not possible_.